# Stack Focus - Boost productivity on Stack Exchange

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

Personalize your Stack Exchange experience. Inspired from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407190/focus-mode-hide-everything-sidebar-footer-except-linked-questions/).

It provides you the ability to toggle the visibility of certain elements on the page, including:

- The "Find a Job" category on the left sidebar.
- The Teams advertisement on the left sidebar.
- The Overflow Blog + Featured on Meta + Hot Meta Posts side widget.
- The Linked Posts sidewidget.
- The Related Posts sidewidget.
- The Hot Network Questions.

### Settings modal can be toggled with the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>** shortcut.

All settings are set to "Show" by default.

#### License

[MIT License](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/LICENSE)

#### Download

**Github:**.

Un-minified: https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/focus-mode/v2.3/script.user.js

Minified: https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/raw/main/scripts/focus-mode/v2.3/script.min.user.js

#### Platform

#### Browser Support

| IE | Chrome | Firefox | Safari | Edge | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ~ 10-11 | ~ 4-20, ✔️ 21+ | ~ 2-27, ✔️ 28+ | ~3.1-6, ✔️ 6.1 + | ✔️ 12+ | ✔️ 12.1+ |

<sup>Support not guaranteed. This graph should only give you an idea. Please consider [editing](https://stackapps.com/posts/8925/edit) to ensure this table is up to date</sup>

**~** = partial

### Change Log

#### v2.3

Added support for all Stack Exchange sites

#### v2.2

Added a Roboto font for browsers which did not have Roboto font automatically installed.

#### v2.1

Fixed a [reported bug](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52142933#52142933) reported by [Kevin M. Mansour](https://stackexchange.com/users/20374110/kevin-m-mansour) probably attributed to low height incompatibilities.

### Code

Written fully with JavaScript. Uses HTML5 Web Storage API to preserve preferences.

Comment: Where can I find settings page :)

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Use the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl + Q**

Comment: Hi Spetric, thank you for your good work, can I have the guide to use this one, I do not know where to start. Thanks.